# Cannot remove SQLite row using 'where' and variable

Tags: python, sqlite, variables, sql-delete

Got a problem, would appreciate any help on it.

I want to remove a row, which was transferred to my func from a variable.
That's the code:

```
con = sql.connect('db.sqlite')
cur = con.cursor()
query = 'delete from media_tmp where media_id="%s"' % media_id.strip()
print(query)
cur.execute(query)
if con:
    con.close()
```

print(query) gives me the following:

```
delete from media_tmp where media_id="737589711821419460_184456611"
```

and when I execute that directly in sqlite, it works perfectly and removes the deserved row. 
but executed by cur.execute(query) doesn't work at all.

The func finishes good, I got no errors.

Comment: sorry, didn't mention that. No errors, finishes perfect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably forgetting to *commit* the change:

```
con.commit()
```

The sqlite3 command line tool auto-commits changes, the `sqlite3` library does not.

You should really use SQL parameters instead of string interpolation:

```
query = 'delete from media_tmp where media_id=?'
cur.execute(query, (media_id.strip(),))
```

Quoting the [`sqlite3` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html):

> Usually your SQL operations will need to use values from Python variables. You shouldn’t assemble your query using Python’s string operations because doing so is insecure; it makes your program vulnerable to an SQL injection attack (see http://xkcd.com/327/ for humorous example of what can go wrong).
>
> Instead, use the DB-API’s parameter substitution. Put `?` as a placeholder wherever you want to use a value, and then provide a tuple of values as the second argument to the cursor’s `execute()` method. (Other database modules may use a different placeholder, such as `%s` or `:1`.)